# Pager property of StoredContact not found

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to extract some properties from a StoredContact-object created in a custom contact store. I do the following to extract a property:

```
StoredContact contact = ...
var properties = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync();
var number = properties[KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone];
```

However, the number type "pager" is not found within the KnownContactProperties-class.

How do I get the pager number from the StoredContact object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [KnownContactProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.personalinformation.knowncontactproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) merely provides some string constants for getting the common property names - it may be the case that pagers were not considered as in widespread use to provide a constant for the property name.

Instead, why not look at what keys are in the `properties` in the debugger for a contact with a pager, and use that instead?

Comment: I did what you said and got the key, "PagerNumber". I do think it is strange that `KnownContactProperties` does not contain all keys, only some. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I suspect the reason makes more sense in differing locales - The last person I knew with a pager got rid of it about 15 years ago. I suspect in some countries, they're still a bit more prevalent...